# Image Entry in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to be able to insert an image inside an input, make a binding if the mail is confirmed or not.
I can't find any way to render the entry for IOS and android
I want to achieve the following[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMOMs.png)

I read the following but it is deprecated
https://xamgirl.com/image-entry-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: You can easily display in icon on top of or next to an entry.  Is there any reason it as to actually render **inside** the entry?

Comment: at the request of client

Comment: You can OVERLAY two things on top of each other. Visually it will look "inside", if you correctly adjust sizes, padding, margin as needed. This can be done using `Grid`, `RelativeLayout`, or `AbsoluteLayout`. Google for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your requirement,it could be achieved by `custom control with bindable property`.However, in Android Renderer, you need make small adjustments in `BitmapDrawable`  method like below:

```
      private BitmapDrawable GetDrawable(string imageEntryImage)
        {
            int resID = Resources.GetIdentifier(imageEntryImage, "drawable", this.Context.PackageName);
            var drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this.Context, resID);
            var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;

            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.P)
            {
                return new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, element.ImageWidth * 2, element.ImageHeight * 2, true));
            }

            return new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, element.ImageWidth, element.ImageHeight, true));
        }
```

**Consume the image entry in backend**:

```
    <local:ImageEntry TextColor="White" 
                          BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                    
                        Image="icon" 
                        Placeholder="Email" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

**Running outcome in iOS:**

[image]

**Running outcome in Android:**

[image]